# How do I access (listen for) the multimedia keys (play/pause) in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, xul, songbird

I want to write a [Songbird](http://getsongbird.com/) extension binds the multimedia keys available on all Apple Mac OS X platforms.  Unfortunately this isn't an easy google search and I can't find any docs.

Can anyone point me resources on accessing these keys or tell me how to do it?

I have extensive programming experience, but this will be my first time coding in both MacOSX and [XUL](http://wiki.songbirdnest.com/Developer/Developer_Intro/Extensions) (Firefox, etc), so any tips on either are welcome.

Please note that these are not regular key events.  I assume it must be a different type of system event that I will need to hook or subscribe to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This blog post has a solution:

http://www.rogueamoeba.com/utm/posts/Article/mediaKeys-2007-09-29-17-00.html

You basically need to subclass `NSApplication` and override `sendEvent`,
looking for special scan codes. I don't know what songbird is, but if it's
not a real application then I doubt you'll be able to do this.

Or maybe you can, a simple category may suffice:

```
@implementation NSApplication(WantMediaKeysCategoryKBye)
- (void)sendEvent: (NSEvent*)event
{
    // intercept media keys here
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your multimedia keys are working in your installation? Every single key generates a scan code which is translated into a key code by the kernel. If xev doesn't show you any keycodes I guess those scan codes aren't mapped and so the kernel has no knowledge of them.

http://gentoo-wiki.com/HOWTO_Use_Multimedia_Keys has a nice explanation of finding key codes and offers help on how you can find raw scan codes and translate them into key codes.

Answer (score 0):

[`xev`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/xev/) might help you if you want to find out which codes are being sent by multimedia keys.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but xev does not receive the multimedia key events.  These are not normal key events, Ukulele for example is not able to receive or reassign them.